# How to Upload and Download File from Grid View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I  am try to Download File from grid view but i face the error like:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\love\Desktop\Crime Management System\Crime Management System\Admin\Data\~\Admin\Data\State and Capital list of India.pdf'.

Upload Aspx Code :

```
Property p = new Property();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FillData();
        }
    }

    private void FillData()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = p.GetFile();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            p.FileName = txtFileName.Text;
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                p.Data = "~/Admin/Data/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(p.Data));
            }
            else
                p.Data = "Data is not Avilable";
        }
        p.CreateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpdate.Text);
        p.Size = txtSize.Text;
        p.UploadFile(p);
        Response.Write("Upload successfull");

    }
```

Source Code:

```
    public void UploadFile(Property p)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("UploadFile", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", p.FileName );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", p.Data);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", p.CreateDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", p.Size);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
    public void DeleteFile(Property p)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteFile", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataId", p.DataId);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    public DataTable GetFile()
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblData", con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

Aspx Code for Download:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/octect-stream";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + e.CommandArgument);
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Admin/Data/") + e.CommandArgument);
            Response.End();
        }


    }
```

Upload and Delete file all things work properly but problem faced during download.

Comment: If i do that then error arise during build like : Error 5 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(string)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\love\Desktop\Crime Management System\Crime Management System\Admin\ManageFileManager.aspx.cs 104 39 Crime Management System

Answer (score 0):

The error-message tells you where the problem is:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\love\Desktop\Crime
>   Management System\Crime Management
>   System\Admin\Data\~\Admin\Data\State and Capital list of India.pdf'

**Admin\Data\~\Admin\Data** -> you can see *Server.MapPath()* already maps to **\Admin\Data** and then you try to map it again, which results in a path who cannot be found. (You can try to enter the path given in your explorer - won't work)

If you add only the file-name to *Server.MapPath()* you should get the right path to download:

```
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
```

Comment: If i do that then error arise during build like : Error 5 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @LoveAajkal If the answer helped you, upvote/accept it so that other user know what was helpful.